# Using json model field with django graphene

Tags: django, django-models, graphql, python-3.6, graphene-python

I'm working with graphql endpoint for my project. One of models has textfield which contains some json. If i request list of my entities via graphql, I'm getting this json like a string. How to reach ability to use it in graphql as nested structure with ability of filtering, choosing some properties etc.

```
class SysObjects(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.BigIntegerField()
    type_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    # status = models.ForeignKey('SysObjectsStatuses', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    data = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True) #json string is here
    visible = models.IntegerField()
    date_actual = models.DateTimeField()
    date_update = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_add = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    orig = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    is_color = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'sys_objects'
        app_label = "default"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 3):

You can declare resolver for data field with a custom type, e.g.

```
import graphene
from graphene.django.types import DjangoObjectType

class SysObjectsType(DjangoObjectType):
    data = DataType()

    class Meta:
        model = SysObjects

    def resolve_data(self, info):
        # What you return here depends on how you are unpacking the JSON data
        return self.data

class DataType(graphene.ObjectType):
    # What you put here depends on how you want to structure the JSON output
    ...
```

You might be able to extend this idea for DataType data to return DataType data, and thus be able to handle arbitrarily deep trees of data.