# Graphene-Django, fetching 10,000+ data points

Tags: python, django, api, graphql, graphene-django

I am building a backend GraphQL service with Django & Graphene and I am having trouble with figuring out what the best way would be to fetch thousands of data points in a performant manner.

Some context, we have an experiment that has 35,000 data points that needs to be displayed on a Plotly plot. The data points are stored in a database table called `data_point`. Here is the schema of this table:

```
data_point_id | value | type | created_at
```

In my Graphene schema, I have a resolver to get all data points for a given experiment as shown below

```
class ExperimentNode(DjangoObjectType):
    users = generic.GenericScalar()
    aliases = generic.GenericScalar()
    properties = generic.GenericScalar()
    data_points = graphene.List(DataPointType)

    class Meta:
        model = Experiment
        # what other filter fields would we want for a batch?
        filter_fields = {
            'experiment_id': ['exact']
        }
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node, )

    def resolve_data_points(self, info, **kwargs):
        try:
            data_points_for_experiment = DataPoint.objects.filter(experiment_id=self.experiment_id)
            data_points = []
            for data_point in data_points_for_experiment:
                value = data_point.numeric_value
                measured_at = data_point.measured_at
                attribute = data_point.measurement_type_id
                data_points.append({
                    "value": value,
                    "measured_at": measured_at,
                    "attribute": attribute
                })
            return data_points
        except Exception:
            return None
```

Here is my query class

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    all_batches = DjangoFilterConnectionField(BatchNode)
```

When I run the query, as expected, it takes a very long time to fetch all 35,000 data points (longer than 10 seconds). I'm still pretty new to Graphene and I'm wondering what the best way would be to fetch all 35,000 points in a fast way. I heard pagination could possibly resolve my issue, but I'm not sure how I would implement such pagination method within Graphene/Django. I know Relay provides a cursor-based pagination, but it limits the maximum amount of values per page to 100.

Any help would be appreciate, and please let me know if I need to provide more code for more clarification.

Thanks!

Comment: use graphql custom types, you can use csv-like format (and treat as one dataset) instead of conversion into bunch of separate/bloated objects/types

Comment: @xadm, do you have an example of how this would be implemented?

Comment: not using python, search for graphql custom json type examples - your data can be an jsoned array or you can use custom encoding/decoding (csv,+ line separator glued string)

Comment: @xadm, I see, though still a bit confused on how this would be implemented with Graphene/Django, do you happen to have any links to any resources?

Comment: just search .... https://stackoverflow.com/a/51068426/6124657